# Does the resolution of a timeseries affect the estimate of the power-spectrum?

Tags: computational-physics, power, statistics, data-analysis, turbulence

I have been trying to estimate the power spectrum of a timeseries using fourier transform.

I noticed that by downsampling my timeseries I get a different spectrum as shown below

[image]

Here you can see  period from the timeseries. In blue the original timeseries with dt= 50 ms and in green the downsampled one with dt~ 0.8 seconds.

[image]

Is this to be expected? Does it mean I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, if you don't downsample properly (i.e., filter beforehand) you get discontinuities, which show up as an $f^{-2}$ power spectrum slope (give or take)...

Comment: @honeste_vivere Thanks for the reply! Is there a specific filter you would suggest?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with the results.  If you care about phase etc. then you need to use a filter where the change in phase resulting from the application of the filter is known so you can correct it.  You should also check to make sure that the code (or software language) you use does a proper normalization during an FFT (i.e., normalizes by N/2*T so the total amplitude isn't off just by using fewer points).

Comment: @honeste_vivere Thanks again! Just to clarify N=number of points in timeseries and T = Duration of timeseries in seconds? Also, if you do care about phase, do you have a suggested algorithm for resampling?